# how to execute its show_info() method

Tags: python

this is how it show display

Commercial
Storeys: 12 , floor area: 48000

Commercial building offices

Commercial
Storeys: 2 , floor area: 100000

Commercial building retailing

this is what i have from my class and main function

```
class Edifice:
    def __init__(self,storeys,area):
        self.__storeys = storeys
        self.__area = area


    def show_info(self):
        print('Storeys:',self.__storeys,', floor area:',self.__area)


class Commercial(Edifice):
    def __init__(self, storeys, area):
        super().__init__(storeys, area)


    def show_info(self):
        print('\n' + "Commercial")
        super(Commercial, self).show_info()
        print("Commercial building offices")


    def show_info(self):
        print('\n' + "Commercial")
        super(Commercial, self).show_info()
        print("Commercial building retailing")
```

The main Fucntion

```
from test1 import Edifice, Commercial

def main():

    c = Commercial(12,48000)
    c.show_info()

    c2 = Commercial(2,100000)
    c2.show_info()


main()
```

the results I get

Commercial
Storeys: 12 , floor area: 48000

Commercial building retailing

Commercial
Storeys: 2 , floor area: 100000

Commercial building retailing

Why is it repeating Commercial building retailing?

Comment: Because you have`print("Commercial building retailing")` in show_info()

Comment: But I also have  print("Commercial building offices")

Comment: First you define method `show_info()` with "Commercial building offices" and then you override that method with `show_info()` with "Commercial building retail"

Comment: Why did you define two `show_info` methods in `Commercial`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: how do I get to display first  "Commercial building offices", than "Commercial building retail" , instead of it repeating like the results I get

Comment: If i put  "Commercial building offices" and "Commercial building retail" in the main function it works, but I need to display from the class but it repeats "Commercial building retail" instead of displaying both the results